# Setting up a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse on Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to get a web project set up for a class that I have this quarter. I currently have Fedora 18 installed and thought it would be good to try to get some practice in with a Java web application since I've never had to do one.

I've installed `eclipse` `eclipse-wpt-*` and `tomcat` packages and for some reason I can't get them working together. Does anybody have any help with how to make these packages get along?

Specifically I got the following error from eclipse

```
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /usr/share/tomcat/conf. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
/usr/share/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)
```

**EDIT:**

I've also tried using the J2EE Preview and got the following error:

```
Could not find required bundle com.sun.el
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you'd already solved this by now, but the only solution I've seen so far is to relax the permissions on tomcat-users.xml and make it readable to others (I assume your only using this for development so should be fine).

```
sudo chmod 0664 /usr/share/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

Another more convoluted solution would be to create a new eclipse user and give them permissions on the file.

Unfortunately, this is still happening for more recent versions of Fedora (currently 20)